# How to shift an input wave in time? in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

The purpose that is sought is to have a signal, I will name it as "A" and a signal "B". Both signals are identical, but B is 5us out of phase from A, the 5us are 250 pulses of the 50MHz clock.

What I tried was to generate a counter from 0 to 249 clock pulses. In pulse 249 the signal B stops and activates (which in this case would be A in a time of 0 seconds), the problem is that B corresponds to A in 5us and not in 0s. Somebody could help me?.

Comment: Do you mean `B` is a delayed version of `A`? In that case, you need some kind of memory (otherwise the system will forget what the old values of `A` were). The simplest way to write this in VHDL would probably be a shift register. You could also implement a circular buffer in a RAM (which could be more efficient).

Comment: Hi Harry. 

As you mention, B is a backward version of A. I see, thank you very much.